# Entered Singapore with a passport with <6 months validity and renewed passport in Singapore. Do I need to update the DE card?

Tags: singapore

My son entered Singapore on a tourist visa with a passport which had less than 6 months validity. I am a Singapore PR and I told the Singapore immigration officer that I intend to renew his passport in Singapore itself. I went to the Indian embassy and they accepted an application for passport renewal even though he is on a tourist visa.

My question is when I get the new passport for my son, his DE card is still linked to the old passport (on which he entered Singapore). When he leaves Singapore will it create any issue?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to exit through automated gates.

You can just carry old and new passport along when you exit singapore and show it to immigration officer. That's all.

You can contact Immigration and Checkpoint Authority, if you are in doubt.

https://www.ica.gov.sg/contactus